# sort file by number after specific word from bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a large file (more than 1000 rows) and I need to sort it by some criteria.
File contains rows like :

```
bla bla bla took 536ms. {"uniqueId":"ygfwyagf","duration":536} []
bla  took 531ms. {"uniqueId":"wdagweg","duration":531} []
[2017-07-26 11:34:04.346533] wgwqegwqeg took 47ms. {qwgwqgce":"local","duration":47} []
[2017-07-2 [bla] Aocal took 41ms. {"uniagwrqgwqrwqg ation":41} []
[2017-07-26 1wergwg  local took 39ms. {"uniqueId"wetgwgweqg gg}
```

Need to sort them by number after word "took"
with awk I can sort them via: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="took") print $(i+1)}'  test | sort -h`
but for the output, I need from an all rows, just to be sorted without losing anything. Unfortunately, the mss are not on the same column (will be easy).

A solution that needs to call out to another interpreter (perl, python, etc) will be accepted if preferable to (faster/simpler/more correct than) a native bash solution.

Comment: Use the `{}` button to code-format blocks of literal content (be that actual code or data). You can use the tag `<!-- language: none -->` above such a block to tell the site not to try to syntax-highlight data.

Comment: BTW, please *don't* tag a language just because you speculate that it might be helpful. That's a good way to annoy a lot of people (subscribed to the tag because they want to answer questions *about* that language).

Comment: The part your code is missing is: delete the "ms." from the next word; and print the line along with it: `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i == "took") {n = $(i+1); sub(/ms\./, "", n); print n, $0; next}}}' file` -- then sort and remove the first word as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to extract the data you want to search on into a column, sort on it, and then remove that column in another pipeline element.

Thus, as an immediate step:

```
gawk 'match($0, /took ([[:digit:]]+)/, m) {printf("%s\t%s\n", m[1], $0)}'
```

This will make your stream look like:

```
536 bla bla bla took 536ms. {"uniqueId":"ygfwyagf","duration":536} []
531 bla  took 531ms. {"uniqueId":"wdagweg","duration":531} []
47  [2017-07-26 11:34:04.346533] wgwqegwqeg took 47ms. {qwgwqgce":"local","duration":47} []
41  [2017-07-2 [bla] Aocal took 41ms. {"uniagwrqgwqrwqg ation":41} []
39  [2017-07-26 1wergwg  local took 39ms. {"uniqueId"wetgwgweqg gg}
```

...at which point you can pass it through `sort -n` to sort on the number at the beginning, and then to a pipeline element that strips that leading value:

```
gawk 'match($0, /took ([[:digit:]]+)/, m) {printf("%s\t%s\n", m[1], $0)}' \
 | sort -n | cut -d $'\t' -f 2-
```

...and we have our output:

```
[2017-07-26 1wergwg  local took 39ms. {"uniqueId"wetgwgweqg gg}
[2017-07-2 [bla] Aocal took 41ms. {"uniagwrqgwqrwqg ation":41} []
[2017-07-26 11:34:04.346533] wgwqegwqeg took 47ms. {qwgwqgce":"local","duration":47} []
bla  took 531ms. {"uniqueId":"wdagweg","duration":531} []
bla bla bla took 536ms. {"uniqueId":"ygfwyagf","duration":536} []
```

Comment: Also known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: @glennjackman, that's a substantial improvement on both readability and efficiency grounds; adopted, many thanks.

Comment: @glennjackman, ooh, good point -- I broke the code there when adopting your prior suggestion. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl, you could write

```
perl -e '
    while (<>) {
        if (/took (\d+)/) {
            push @{$lines{$1}}, $_;
        } 
    } 
    for $num (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %lines) {
        print join("", @{$lines{$num}});
    }
' file
```

or, as line noise

```
perl -lnE'/took (\d+)/&&push@{$l{$1}},$_}END{say@{$l{$_}}for sort{$a<=>$b}keys%l' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 gawk '/took/ { cnt++;match($0,/[[:digit:]]+ms/);num=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2);tim[num]=$0 } END { asorti(tim,tim1);for ( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) print tim[tim1[i]] }' filename
```

As an alternative, more succinct way to use gawk is to use the time stamps as the indices of an array (tim) and then use the function asorti to sort the indexes into another array (tim1) the sorted indices in tim1 are then used to extract the data in tim.

Output:

```
[2017-07-26 1wergwg  local took 39ms. {"uniqueId"wetgwgweqg gg}
[2017-07-2 [bla] Aocal took 41ms. {"uniagwrqgwqrwqg ation":41} []
[2017-07-26 11:34:04.346533] wgwqegwqeg took 47ms. 
{qwgwqgce":"local","duration" :47} []
bla  took 531ms. {"uniqueId":"wdagweg","duration":531} []
bla bla bla took 536ms. {"uniqueId":"ygfwyagf","duration":536} []
```

Comment: The only disadvantage I can see here is that it requires data to fit in RAM, whereas GNU `sort` can spool out to individually-sorted temporary files (and then do a merge sort to combine them) when handling data larger than available RAM.